# use list values for dataframe name with using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

this is `symbol_list = ['VETUSDT', 'TRXUSDT', 'THETAUSDT','STXUSDT']`
i want to create 4 dataFrame files as the same name list values.
result:
`VETUSDT =DataFrame` (it is empty now it is not a problem)

```
TRXUSDT = DataFrame
THETAUSDT= DataFrame
STXUSDT= DataFrame
```

how can i do it forexample with a for loop?
thank you

Comment: It's *much* better to keep a parallel list of dataframes (or use a mapping, e.g., a `dict`) imho; but if you *must*, then `for sym in symbol_list: globals()[sym] = pd.DataFrame()` will result in empty dataframes into the namespace with the names from the `symbol_list`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the pandas library?

If so your_data_Frame_object.to_csv('data.csv') should create a csv with your dataFrame data.

```
symbol_list = ['VETUSDT', 'TRXUSDT', 'THETAUSDT','STXUSDT']

for i in symbol_list:
    #Create filename
    filename = i + ".csv"
    #assuming your dataFrame object will be called the same as the list entry
    i.to_csv(filename)
```

If you're not using pandas you can create a csv like this:

```
import csv

header = ['name', 'area', 'country_code2', 'country_code3']
data = ['Afghanistan', 652090, 'AF', 'AFG']

symbol_list = ['VETUSDT', 'TRXUSDT', 'THETAUSDT','STXUSDT']

for i in symbol_list:
    filename = i + ".csv"
    with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        # write the header
        writer.writerow(header)
        # write the data
        writer.writerow(data)
```

The example was taken form here: https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-write-csv-file/

The Pandas info from here: https://realpython.com/pandas-read-write-files/#write-a-csv-file

Comment: yes i use pandas. 
for example :
symbol_list = ['VETUSDT', 'TRXUSDT', 'THETAUSDT']
i want to do this: 
VETUSDT=pd.read_csv("VETUSDT.csv",decimal=".")
TRXUSDT=pd.read_csv("TRXUSDT.csv",decimal=".")
THETAUSDT=pd.read_csv("THETAUSDT.csv",decimal=".")
i have csv files. i want to csv to pandas dataframe. 
but for example if symbol_list have 500 different values, can i do this with a for loop or another way? thank you